# Right use of free function which changes data

Tags: c, free

please, can you tell me if I use free in my function the right way?
I checked my code with valgrind and no errors occured.

```
void strconcat (char **str1, const char *str2) {
    unsigned long str1len = strlen(*str1);
    unsigned long str2len = strlen(str2);

    char *tempStr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str1len + str2len + 1));
    memcpy(tempStr, *str1, str1len);
    memcpy(&(tempStr[str1len]), str2, (str2len + 1));

    free(*str1);
    *str1 = tempStr;
}
```

In the main-function I'm calling my function this way:

```
int main() {

    char *str1 = malloc(25);
    str1 = strcpy(str1, "First part of the string");

    char *str2 = malloc(16);
    str2 = strcpy(str2, " - second part.");
    printf("%s\n", str2);

    strconcat(&str1, str2);

    printf("%s\n", str1);

    free(str1);
    free(str2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The only thing is you're not appending the null character at the end of concatination.

Comment: So long as your function is always passed a pointer-to-pointer that dereferences to *only* a valid allocation address, it should be ok, but egads...

Comment: I add the null character in the second memcpy with (str2len + 1)

Comment: A small improvement would be to replace your malloc and strcpy lines in main with strdup. strdup mallocs and returns the pointer to a copy of the string you pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're using it correctly. In `strconcat()`, you'll lose the memory originally allocated to `str1` when you assign the newly concatenated string to it, so you should `free()` it before that happens. After you return from that function, you still have two dynamically allocated blocks of memory, so you should free those both two.

Valgrind is generally pretty trustworthy, so you should have some confidence in it, provided that you're running through all the relevant different paths of execution.

Whether what you are doing with your function is a good idea, though, is another thing entirely. If someone passed in a pointer to a string literal then your function would fail catastrophically. There are also some other problems with your code, including that `strconcat` is a reserved identifier, but for what it does, you're using `free()` correctly.

Comment: This function is only a little test how it is done to change the memory and data of a function argument without returning a additional pointer.

Answer (score 0):

After free in `void strconcat()`function you are assinging malloc'd `tempStr` variable to  `*str1`, So you not getting any error when you debug with valgrind.

Remove     `*str1 = tempStr` line from function, now compile and run the program your program will get crashed. Because of double free.

**EDIT:**

You have to free all the memory allocated using malloc. You have to free the memory of `str1` before assigning to some other variable to avoid memory leak.

```
free(*str1) - free for memory allocated to str1 in main() function
free(str1) - free for memory allocated to tempStr in strconcat() function.
free(str2) - free for memory allocated to str2 in main function.
```

Comment: Yes, I know.The question is, do I need to call free in my function to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: I think that's why it is assigned the value before exiting the function. I don't see any problem

Comment: @TedFerry yes. you have to free from your function.